# How to use Schema.org for Adverts on a website - WPAdBlock

Tags: seo, advertising, microdata

I'm trying to use schema.org to indicate advertisements on my website.

I'm concerned that putting adverts within the content of a blog page will hurt my SEO and I'm hoping using schema might help make things clear to search engines.

This is what I have so far, an image with a link.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WPAdBlock">
    <a href="" itemprop="url"><img src="" itemprop="image"></a>
</div>
```

- is the above schema I'm using correct?
- should I rather be inserting these adverts with javascript or jquery rather than just html?

I am not using an ad network these are custom ads.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, your use of Microdata and schema.org is correct.

Instead of `div`, you might want consider using the sectioning element [`aside`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2014/CR-html5-20140731/sections.html#the-aside-element):

> The element can be used for […] advertising, […]

That way the advertisement is separate from the main content flow of your document.

Oh, and don’t forget to provide an `alt` attribute for the image.

Depending on the ad, you might also want to use the `nofollow` link type for the link ([Google urges to use it for "paid links"](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/96569?hl=en)).

For transparency (and, sometimes, legal) reasons, you might want to explicitly note that it’s an advertisement. For example, by using an "Advertisement" heading (which makes sense if you are using a sectioning element, and is nice if you want screen reader users to easily skip it if they want to), or just a simple note, or maybe a link to a page explaining why you are advertising and what happens with possible income or referrer data etc.

Including it with JavaScript? Well, I wouldn’t do it for the obvious reason that users without JS wouldn’t be able to see your ad.

Comment: Useful info, I appreciate your input. Couldn't find much on schema and adverts.

Comment: You should probably update the link to https://developers.google.com/search/docs/crawling-indexing/qualify-outbound-links
Also the preferred link type is now `rel="sponsored"`

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct.
You can test it in the [Google Webmasters tools](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets).
In terms of SEO you should insert the ads with JavaScript so it won't be indexed by robots.

Comment: Google has been rendering JavaScript for years now and includes the results as content for the page.